# FireBase SDK for Unity iOS missing FireApp Class

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, unity-game-engine

We are trying to integrate FireBase SDK in Unity Project for iOS platform. For testing, we imported `FireBaseAnalytic.unitypackage` in an empty project, and put GoogleService-Info.plist on `Assets` folder.

Once we export XCode project from Unity and build in XCode we are getting few errors about missing few classes from:

[image: FireApp.o error scrennshot]

we also tried to install Cocoapods file and place Podfile in XCode Project. Cocoapod file contains information as below:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Unity-iPhone' do
  # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
  # use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Unity-iPhone

  target 'Unity-iPhone Tests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing

    pod 'Firebase/AdMob'
    pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
    pod 'Firebase/Auth'
    pod 'Firebase/Crash'
    pod 'Firebase/Database'
    pod 'Firebase/DynamicLinks'
    pod 'Firebase/Invites'
    pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
    pod 'Firebase/Performance'
    pod 'Firebase/RemoteConfig'
    pod 'Firebase/Storage'

  end

end
```

even these all changes do not help to build test project even just with Firebase Analytic.